# Sitecore - Multilist with Search field

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.2

I am on `Sitecore v8.2`

Using `Multilist with Search` field, is there a way to filter by multiple templates?

`TemplateFilter` seems to work with just one Template ID (tried pipe delimited value and that didn't work). I would rather not use `Filter=_templatename` and `Filter=_templateid` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bit tricky with Sitecore.

As you wrote, `TemplateFilter` only works with 1 value and it doesn't care about pipe separated template ids.

But you can achieve what you need with `Filter` parameter. The syntax is:

```
Filter=_template:{A87A00B1-E6DB-45AB-8B54-636FEC3B5523}|_template:{DA1684ED-C7A7-4B96-B019-C1E3D5169A6A}
```

Comment: Is there any symbol to use OR instead of AND? For example: `Filter=_template:{A87A00B1-E6DB-45AB-8B54-636FEC3B5523}||_template:{DA1684ED-C7A7-4B96-B019-C1E3D5169A6A}`

Comment: Ok, I ended up finding how to do it with OR: `Filter=_template:{A87A00B1-E6DB-45AB-8B54-636FEC3B5523},{DA1684ED-C7A7-4B96-B019-C1E3D5169A6A}`

Comment: @Marek is there a way to restrict it by _parent ?

Comment: @Sidso use `Filter=_parent:{7F65E885-32A3-4BFB-B2F1-3686C29E56C9}`

Comment: @Marek I am trying to exclude the item with the help of  &Filter=-_parent: but it doesn't work. Is there a way to directly exclude the item? Can we have a chat about this plz?